# SQL Server - Dynamically Filling the column Values with 0's as per the fixed length

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column with the given values

```
MRN
1946
456
27
557
```

The column values length is fixed.
If at all any value is less than 6characters,then it should concate 0's to the left and make it 6characters length.
The desired output is

```
MRN 
001946
000456
000027
000557
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called left paddings.  In SQL Server, this is typically done with more basic string operations:

```
select right(replicate('0', 6) + mrn, 6)
```

If `mrn` is a number, then use the `concat()` function:

```
select right(concat(replicate('0', 6), mrn), 6)
```

Comment: I suggest to apply RTRIM() bevore you apply RIGHT() if it is a CHAR field.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `FORMAT` function for this. ([Demo](https://rextester.com/URFU46744))

```
SELECT FORMAT(MRN ,'D6')
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change the number 6 to whatever your total length needs to be:**

```
SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(EmployeeId)) + EmployeeId
If the column is an INT, you can use RTRIM to implicitly convert it to a VARCHAR
```

**SELECT REPLICATE('0',6-LEN(RTRIM(EmployeeId))) + RTRIM(EmployeeId)
And the code to remove these 0s and get back the 'real' number:**

```
SELECT RIGHT(EmployeeId,(LEN(EmployeeId) - PATINDEX('%[^0]%',EmployeeId)) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by adding leading zero's

```
select RIGHT('0000'+CAST(MRN AS VARCHAR(10)),6)
```

Comment: Although the OP's extensive sample data didn't have any single-digit values, you might want to toss one more `'0'` in there.